# How can you change a table td background in php?

Tags: php

I just started learning PHP and I made a webpage that has a table with 3 columns and it has a submit style button that should be able to change the background color of the first and third column if the user clicks on the button. I know this would be a lot easier with Javascript.

Here's my code

```
<table>
<tr><td bgcolor="blue">
<p> First Column </p>
</td>
<td>
<p> Second Column </p>
</td>
<td bgcolor="green">
<p> Third Column </p>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="color" value="Color">
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<!--html-->
```

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['color']))
{
echo "<td background-color:blue> </td>";
}
?>
```

I apolgize if my code is completely off

Comment: `style="background-color: blue;"` - Helps if you use proper inline CSS syntax  You're correct though; this should be done via Javascript. Front-end changes should be handled by front-end languages.

Comment: Remember that PHP runs on the server, so by the time your user is pressing buttons on forms, the PHP involvement is over.

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this helpful?

```
<td style="<?php if (isset($_POST['color'])) { echo 'background-color: blue;'; } ?>">
```